# Kineticjs - Creating own line style

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I am working on an image editor with kineticjs. So it's time to make nice brushes. I would like to use png images for this with a different set of alpha values for each pixel, depending on the brush type, and changing the color once they are added to the layer.

I would like to know, how can I achieve this? I made a simple painter following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708016/paint-application-with-kinetic-js) But what I want is to reduce the opacity in some parts of the shape that we use as base for painting lines, like in [this image](http://madrov.com/src/img/Lines.jpg). Notice that the first and the last are the same, just the opacity in the last is less. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The stroke of a Kinetic.Line cannot use a fillPattern (it's a stroke without any fill).